# SVG 1px Sliver Showing Randomly

Tags: html, svg

Designing a site and having an issue with an inline SVG graphic. On the homepage , the big red angled block that sits behind the text for the event slide seems to have a 1pm thin sliver to the left of it. The area that would normally be an edge if it was a full on square.

This appears on mobile phones (as it's responsive), and also in browser windows when resizing smaller to simulate a mobile width. All attempts by me and my people to resolve this strange issue haven't worked yet. Can anyone lend a hand?

[Link](http://clients.realintegrated.com/michiganopera/)

[image]

Comment: I'll add that both inline SVG and linked via url() have all given the same outcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an artifact of rounding the size of the image to an integer number of pixels, and it's coming from the following element in the SVG

```
<use xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="#7F0000"
     sketch:type="MSShapeGroup"
     xmlns:sketch="http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch/ns"
     xlink:href="#path-1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"/>
```

I'm not familiar enough with Sketch's SVG export to say how to eliminate it.

Comment: Yeah. The only way we could remedy it was to recreate it. And somehow were still having problems weirdly enough. Not related to that 1px line anymore thankfully.